# Update JSON data in Swift Table View

Tags: ios, json, swift

I am new to swift programming. I created a simple webservice to connect with swift app. Then I retrieved JSON data as a list in to the table view and insert data in to the web service. Now I want to update json data row in the table view. Please anyone help me

I used this code to insert data.

```
@IBAction func btnInsert(sender: AnyObject) {

    let companyName = txtcompanyName.text
    let phoneNumber = txtphoneNumber.text
    let country = txtCountry.text
    let address = txtAddress.text
    let email = txtEmail.text
    let password = txtPassword.text


    // Send HTTP POST

    let myUrl = NSURL(string: "http://localhost:8888/MAMP/appconnect/userRegister.php");
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL:myUrl!);
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST";

    let postString = "companyName=\(companyName!)&phoneNumber=\(phoneNumber!)&country=\(country!)&address=\(address!)&email=\(email!)&password=\(password!)";

    request.HTTPBody = postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
        data, response, error in

        if error != nil {
            print("error=\(error)")
        }

        do {
            let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .MutableContainers) as? NSDictionary

            if let parseJSON = json {
                let resultValue = parseJSON["status"] as! String!
                print("result: \(resultValue)")

                var isUserRegistered:Bool = false
                if(resultValue == "Success") {
                    isUserRegistered = true
                }

                var messageToDisplay:String = parseJSON["message"] as! String
                if(!isUserRegistered) {
                    messageToDisplay = parseJSON["message"] as! String
                }

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {

                    //Display alert message with confirmation
                    let myAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: messageToDisplay, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

                    let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default){ action in
                        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
                    }
                    myAlert.addAction(okAction)
                    self.presentViewController(myAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
                })
            }
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Either describe what you have done step by step or add some code you have written.

Comment: I added the code sample.How is that?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any code in the snippet above which updates the table view with a new row. The steps you need to follow to add a new row in your tableview are

1. Update your data source (array, dictionary - whatever is used to populate the table)
2. Insert a row in your tableview by either using https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableview/1614879-insertrows or by reloading the tableview (the former is preferred)

This could be done right where you display the alert.

If you are facing some other issue like the data not being reflected in the table, you might want to add more details to the question